# GridView : Bind Multiple value from database in single column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want data in gridview like this:

```
CategoryName    Subcategory Name
--------------------------------
Abc             Abc1,abc2,abc3
Bcs             Bcs1,bcs2
def             Null / No Record
```

How can I do that?

okay i want data from database by using single table. i have one table categories in which i have field like categryid, parentid,name. when parentid is 0 then its known by Categories else all other is subCategories.

I Am using asp.net with c# and i want to do this in gridview with using boundfield. for categories i have done but for sub categories i dont have any idea how to do.

subcategories is idedntify by its parentid. in sub categories parentid =categryid

Comment: There are numerous ways. Without *any* detail on how you populate your GridView, with what data, from where, it's impossible to give a definitive answer. Imagine we have no idea what you're doing, then add the details needed to answer your question. =)

Comment: okay i want data from database by using single table. i have one table categories in which i have field like catid, parentid,name. when parentid is 0 then its known by Categories else all other is subCategories.

Comment: I Am using asp.net with c# and i want to do this in gridview with using boundfield. for categories i have done but for sub categories i dont have any idea how to do.

Comment: subcategories is idedntify by its parentid. in sub categories parentid =categryid

Comment: For your additional information here, please click the "edit" link just below your question and put those details in the question itself. That makes it easier to find the relevant and important information you want to convey.

Comment: If you are struck up with writing query,here it goes..select t1.CategoryName,
c.name as SubcategoryName
from
(select name as CategoryName
from Categories
where parentid=0)t1
Left outer join Categories c on c.parentId in (t1.CategoryName)
order by t1.CategoryName

Comment: @MahaSwetha i used that query before but its give me static data only for which have parentid=0 but i want data in grid where parentid=gridview.selectdrow.categryid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in your table is something like this

CategoryId|  ParentID| Name |
  1       |     0    |  A   |,
  2       |     1    |  B   |,
  3       |     0    |  C   |,
  4       |     3    |  D   |

You can do something like

```
Create Table #ReportTable(Id identity int,CategoryId int,Category varchar(10),SubCategory Varchar(10))

Declare @CountOfRecords int = Select count(categoryid) from categories

Declare @TableIterator int = 1

While  @TableIterator <= @CountOfRecords
Begin

       Declare @ParentId int = (Select ParentId From Categories Where CategoryId=@TableIterator)   

       If @ParentId = 0
       Begin
             Insert Into #ReportTable(CategoryId,Category)
             Select CategoryId,Category  
             From Categories
             Where  CategoryId = @TableIterator
       End  
       Else
       Begin
             Update #ReportTable
             Set    SubCategory = 
             (Select SubCategory From Categories Where  CategoryId = @TableIterator)
             And Id = @ParentId   
       End

        Set @TableIterator = @TableIterator + 1
End
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i think its become long process for me and i want to do that thing via short n simple way.